# How to send embeds using the requests module discord.py

Tags: python, json, python-requests, discord.py, webhooks

My code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
 await ctx.send(f"pong <@{ctx.author.id}>!")
 url = "webhook url"
 data = {
  embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Colour.blue(), title="test")
  embed.description = "test"
 }
 print(requests.post(url, json=data))



bot.run("token")
```

I tried to send embeds using the requests json type posting, but there was an error, I dont want to use the Webhook module I want to use the requests module. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you want to use the raw API rather than what discord.py offers you, you will have to create the JSON data you want to post yourself by following [Discord's Documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook).

The data you post will be a dictionary - your current content in that `data` dictionary is not a valid dictionary either, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) on what a dictionary exactly is and how it works - that contains the various field described in the table on Discord's Documentation. One of the field you're searching for is the `embeds` field which is a list of [embed objects](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object). This object has the `title`, `description` and `color` field which you can set individually - see the documentation about their type etc.

A small working example based on your existing code would be

```py
data = {
    "embeds": [
        {
            "title": "test",
            "color": discord.Color.blue().value,
            "description": "test",
        }
    ]
}

requests.post(webhook_url, json=data)
```

This will result in the following

[image: Result when executing webhook]

Do note that for the color you can use any integer value that is a valid color, you could set the blue color yourself with `"color": 0x3498DB` instead of `discord.Color.blue().value`